# Showing that if $u = \sqrt{2}-1$ and $a<b$ then $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ $u^n < b-a$ and then that $a<mu^n<b$ for some $m \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Suppose you have $u = \sqrt{2} - 1$, show that $\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a < b$ we can find $n \in \mathbb{N}^{>0}$ such that $0 < u^n <b-a$. Then, once the $n$ if found, show that there exists a $m \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a < m u^n < b$

So I managed to prove the first part. I did it this way:
First of all, suppose $b-a \geq 1$ then as $u<1$ it's enough to take $n=1$, and we have $0<u^1<b-a$. Now suppose that $b-a <1$, then define a sequence such that $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{>0}} \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}^{>0}}$ such that $u_n = (\sqrt{2}-1)^n$. Then, $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$, $u_n >0$, and $\frac{u_{n+1}}{u_n} = (\sqrt{2}-1)<1$ thus it is decreasing. Thus $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}^{>0}}$ converges to $0$. That means that $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}, \forall n \geq N, |u_n| < \epsilon$ So it suffices to take $\epsilon = b-a$ and then there exists  $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $0<(\sqrt{2}-1)^n < b-a$.

Now for the second part, we have $a <u^n + a < b$ and also $u^n < u^n + a$ and  as $\mathbb{Z}$ has the Archimedean property, $\exists m \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $m u^n > u^n + a$. Thus we have $a < u^n < u^n +a < m u^n $. Now, all is left to do is to show that $mu^n <b$, but I don't know how to proceed to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among all the integers $m$ such that $mu^n>u^n+a$, take the smallest one.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$\dfrac1{u}
=\dfrac1{\sqrt{2}-1}
=\sqrt{2}+1
$.

Therefore,
by Bernoulli's inequality,
$\dfrac1{u^n}
=(1+\sqrt{2})^n
\gt n\sqrt{2}
$,
so
$u^n
\lt \dfrac1{n\sqrt{2}}
$.
(This is,
of course,
a poor inequality,
but it gives a easily computable
value for $n$.)

Therefore,
if 
$b-a \gt  \dfrac1{n\sqrt{2}}
$,
or
$n \gt \dfrac1{\sqrt{2}(b-a)}$,
then
$u^n < b-a$.

This works for any $u$
with
$0 < u < 1$.
Write
$u = \dfrac1{1+v}$
and use
$v$
wherever
$\sqrt{2}$ appears
above.